# Gorm does not autogenerate model ID

Tags: grails-orm

I have a following model and seems like gorm does not autogenerate the ID for that.

```golang
type Customer struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username            string  `gorm:"unique;type:varchar(100); NOT NULL;" json:"username"`
    Password            string  `gorm:"type:varchar(100) NOT NULL;" json:"password"`
    Email               string  `gorm:"unique; type:varchar(100) NOT NULL;" json:"email"`
    PurchasedProductsId string  `gorm:"primaryKey;unique;" json:"purchased_products_id"`
    PurchasedProducts   Product `gorm:"foreignKey:ID;references:PurchasedProductsId;"`
    CreatedAt           string  `gorm:"uniqueIndex;type:date;" json:"createdAt"`
}
```

Also there is a method that creates this object.

```golang
func (this *Customer) CreateObject(ObjectData struct {
    Username string
    Password string
    Email    string
}, Validator BaseModelValidator, PurchasedProducts ...[]Product) (*gorm.DB, []ValidationError) {

    ValidatedData, Errors := Validator.Validate(map[string]string{
        "Username": ObjectData.Username,
        "Email":    ObjectData.Email,
        "Password": ObjectData.Password,
    })
    if Errors != nil {
        return nil, Errors
    }

    newCustomer := Customer{
        Username: ValidatedData["Username"],
        Email:    ValidatedData["Email"],
        Password: ValidatedData["Password"],
    }

    Transaction := Database.Model(&customer).Create(&newCustomer)
    fmt.Print(Transaction.Error)
    return Transaction, []ValidationError{}
```

When I'm trying to create object it always responds with

```
models.go:307 ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint (SQLSTATE 23502)
[9.030ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO "customers" ("username","password","email","created_at") VALUES ('TestUser','TestPassword','testEmail@gmail.com','2022-07-31 22:16:05.796') RETURNING "purchased_products_id","id"
ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint (SQLSTATE 23502)[GIN]
```

Am I Need to add `ID` Field Directly or there is some dark magic involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the ID field to the customer struct and you need to add a id field to the table customers the type is a bigint